# No "bash_profile" on MacOS Monterey

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables

The shell I'm currently using is bash. The file ~/.bash_profile doesn't exist(it exists now that I created it by accident while trying to access it, but it's empty).

If I try the command "printenv" it shows a list of variables. Where are those located if there is no bash_profile? Even ~/.zprofile doesn't exist(in case for some reason I was wrong and was using zshell instead)

Comment: For bash, read [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) -- tl;dr, /etc/profile, and any files it sources.

Comment: Even in the complete absence of any configuration files, your shell could inherit environment variables from its parent process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at /etc (or /private/etc).
There you can find a bashrc and also profile, zprofile, zshrc etc.